# Why do i keep getting an "invalid value" error message after making a POST request

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a Category-collection on MongoDB using Mongoose. I have written my CategorySchema and also written the code to create a new category but i keep getting an "invalid Value" error message when I make a post request to the Create new category route from Postman.
Here is the snippet of my CategorySchema file.

Category.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CategorySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    unique: true
  }
},
{
  timestamps: true
});

Category = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
module.exports = Category;
```

Here is the createCategory.js file

```
router.post('/', [
  // Validating Category name
  check('name is required').trim().not().isEmpty()
], async (req, res) => {
  
  // If Errors from Validating
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
    console.log(errors)
    return res.status(400).json({ error: errors.array()[0].msg })
  }
  // Parsing name from req.body
  const { name } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);

  try {
    let category = await Category.findOne({ name });

    // If category exists
    if(category){
      res.status(403).json({ error: 'Category already exists'})
    }
    const newCategory = new Category({name});
    // Saving new category
    category = await newCategory.save();
    console.log(category);
    return res.json(category);
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(console.error);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
})
```

Here is the error message i Keep getting

```
formatter: [Function: formatter],
  errors: [
    {
      value: '',
      msg: 'Invalid value',        
      param: 'name is required',   
      location: 'body'
    }
  ]
```

Comment: seems like your ORM throws the error you mentioned. why don't you add edge case branching like name is an empty string or undefined.

Comment: plus check out the body parser module is attached on your app or router. Express doesn't provide it for default.